# add new xml element to existing elements

Tags: java, android, xml

so I'm trying to make my first android app.  First time programming in java, though I am used to C# which is similar.  Basically, in the app, there's a button, and when you click it it adds a few text fields for the person to fill out, which then once done will collapse to save space.

What I'm struggling with is inserting new xml structures.  Everything I've found online seems either overly complicated, or permanently saves the xml file of the app, which I'm not looking to do.

```
var a = document.getElementById("id");
a.innerHTML = "<objects></objects>";
```

that's what it would be, more or less, in javascript.  I'm just unsure where to start in java.  I saw about using the document/transformer objects but only saw ways to permanently save the xml file using them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add anything programmatically, you'd want to add widgets like an `EditText` by using a `LayoutInflator`

If you know what widgets you are going to have before hand, you want to define those in your XML before run time.

Answer (score 0):

Unless these fields are going to be determined at runtime, it will likely be easiest to define them in XML, and set their visibility to GONE. You can also do this with a whole ViewGroup like LinearLayout, but here's what a single edit text will look like:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

When the button click happens, set the visibility to VISIBLE.

After the need is gone, you can change the visibility back to GONE, but the reference to it will still contain any text the user put in.